# Dijkstra Program

Tags: c++, dijkstra

I am having trouble with functions that I have used before in different programs and I have come to a brick wall with converting them to be used in this new program. Dijkstra.cpp reads information about a weighted graph from the standard input
and prints the description of the input graph, the shortest path from the 
start vertex and the end vertex, and the distance of that path to the 
standard ouput.

Here are the **ALL** errors I receive (given, it is an incomplete program as is):

[image: attach1]
[image: attach2]

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int trace = 0;

//An object of type Edge is a cell in an adjacency list and represents an edge
//of the graph.

struct Edge 
{
    int from;           //The 'from' direction of the edge.
    int to;         //The 'to' direction of the edge.
    double weight;      //The weight of the edge from u to v.
    Edge* next;     //A pointer to the next edge in the linked list.

    Edge(int u, int v, double w, Edge* nextEdge)
    {
        from = u;
        to = v;         
        weight = w;     
        next = nextEdge;
    }
};


//An object of type Vertex represents information about one vertex in a graph.

struct Vertex       
{
    Edge* edgeList;     //A pointer to a linked list of all edges 
                    //from v to another vertex.

    double time;        //A real number representing the shortest
                    //distance from the start vertex.

    int sender;     //Used with the above real number, it begins 
                //finding the shortest path starting from v to
                //the sender. 

    Vertex()
    {
        edgeList = NULL;
        time = -1;
        sender = -1;
    }
};


//An object of type graph represents a weighted graph.

struct Graph
{
    int numVertices;    //The number of verticies in the graph.
    int numEdges;       //The number of edges in the graph.

    Vertex* vertices;   //An array for verticies utilizing a Vertex
                        //structure that gives information about a
                        //specific vertex.

    Graph(int nV)
    {
        numVertices = nV;
        vertices = new Vertex[nV+1];
        numEdges = 0;
    }
};



//insertEdge inserts an edge into the graph g.

void insertEdge(int u, int v, int w, Graph* g)
{
    Edge newEdge;
    newEdge.from = u;
    newEdge.to = v;
    newEdge.weight = w;

    if(g->numVertices > g->numEdges)
    {   
        g->[g->numEdges] = newEdge;
        g->numEdges++;
    }
}

//insertOpposite inserts an edge going the opposite way
//as insertEdge does into graph g.

void insertOpposite(int u, int v, int w, Graph* g)
{
    Edge newEdge;
    newEdge.from = v;
    newEdge.to = u;
    newEdge.weight = w;

    if(g->numVertices > g->numEdges)
    {       
        g->vertices[g->numEdges] = newEdge;
        g->numEdges++;
    }
}


//readGraph reads a graph and is also able to insert edges into a graph.

Graph* readGraph()
{
    int nV, u,v,w, edges = 0;

    scanf("%i", &nV);

    Graph* g = new Graph(nV);

    while(true)
    {
        scanf("%i", &u);
        if(u == 0)
        {
                break;
        }

        scanf("%i", &v);
        scanf("%i", &w);

        insertEdge(u, v, w, g);
        insertOpposite(u, v, w, g);

        edges++;
    }

    g->totalEdges = edges;  

    return g;
}


//writeGraph prints a formatted chart from graph g 
//that includes the amount of vertices and edges along with 
//the weight that corresponds to each edge.

void writeGraph(Graph* g)
{
    printf("\nThere are %i vertices and %i edges\n", g->numVertices,
        g->numEdges);

    printf("\n The edges are as follows.");

    for(int n = 0; n < g->totalEdges; n++)
    {
        printf("(%i,", g->vertices[n].vertex1);
        printf("%i)  ", g->vertices[n].vertex2);
        printf("weight %3i\n", g->vertices[n].weight);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Edge newEdge;` calls the default constructor. You created a custom constructor so no default constructor is created by the compiler. Either create your own default constructor or call your custom constructor with `Edge newEdge(u, v, w, nullptr);`. The error messages are pretty clear. Read them and do what the compiler recommends.

Comment: That number of errors goes way beyond asking a single question. Focus on the first one (maybe also post one or two after the first if they seem related). Trim the code to a [mcve]. Also, copying the error messages as text rather than an image would (be easier for you and would) make your question accessible to a wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

I won't go through each error exhaustively, but here is a general strategy for resolving these errors.

When dealing with error messages from the compiler, it is generally a good practice to **start with the first error, deal with it, and then attempt to compile again**. Oftentimes, a single issue will result in multiple error messages, and resolving one problem can give clues to the rest. If nothing else, handling one thing at a times helps keep things manageable.

### Let's look at that first error message:

```
dijkstra.cpp: In function ‘void insertEdge(int, int, int, Graph*)
dijkstra.cpp:152:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘Edge::Edge()’
    Edge newEdge;
         ^
```

### 1. Look at the line that is triggering the error.

Sometimes there will be something obvious at that line (or perhaps the line above it). A missing semi-colon, a forgotten argument, a typo, etc.

Your compiler has told you where to look. The error is in `dijkstra.cpp` at line number `152`. It's also given us the signature of the function it is in: `void insertEdge(int, int, int, Graph*)`. In fact, it's even pinpointed where it realized there was something wrong: when your program tries to create an `Edge` called `newEdge`.

### 2. Interpret the error message.

For non-obvious mistakes, you may have to dig into what the error message is saying. In this case the error listed is: `no matching function for call to 'Edge::Edge()'`.

That seems fairly self-explanatory to me, but of course, that depends upon the experience level of the person reading the message. If I don't understand an error message, I employ a simple strategy: I Google it. Removing the names specific to your program will be useful, so in this case I would likely search for `"error: no matching function for call to"`. Doing so brings up many results for programmers facing similar errors.

In this specific case, the compiler is saying that you are trying to call the function `Edge::Edge()` but it can't find a function that matches that. `Edge::Edge()` would be the constructor for your `Edge` struct - but you've only defined one constructor, and it takes several arguments, so the compiler doesn't know how to construct an `Edge` without any arguments.

### 3. Fix the error

For this specific error, you could change the referenced line to create an `Edge` using the arguments. Something like:

```
Edge newEdge(0, 0, 0.0, nullptr)
```

But that's probably not what you want. More likely, you want to add a default constructor to your `Edge` struct.

```
struct Edge 
{
    ...
    Edge(int u, int v, double w, Edge* nextEdge)
    {
        from = u;
        to = v;         
        weight = w;     
        next = nextEdge;
    }
    Edge() = default; // Creates a default constructor; leaves values uninitialized
};
```

or

```
struct Edge 
{
    ...
    Edge(int u, int v, double w, Edge* nextEdge)
    {
        from = u;
        to = v;         
        weight = w;     
        next = nextEdge;
    }
    Edge() : from(0), to(0), weight(0.0), next(nullptr) {} // Initializes members to a set of defaults
};
```

or

```
struct Edge 
{
    ...
    Edge(int u = 0, int v = 0, double w = 0.0, Edge* nextEdge = nullptr) // Defines default values so that constructor can be called with 0-4 arguments
    {
        from = u;
        to = v;         
        weight = w;     
        next = nextEdge;
    }
};
```

### 4. Repeat

Now you re-compile your program. Hopefully, the number of error messages has decreased. Regardless, you look at the first error on the list, and you repeat this process until your program compiles without errors.